# scp copy direction: what is source, what is target?

Tags: scp

man synopsis for scp is:

> scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

What is source, what is target? I'm always wondering in which direction the copying takes place. How is it defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unix commands almost always (with **very** few exceptions) have source before target.  And most allow multiple sources before the final target if it makes sense to do so.

That includes `scp`.

Some commands (like the GNU versions of `cp` and `mv`) have an option (e.g. `-t` or `--target-directory=DIRECTORY`) that allow you to put the target first - **but the default is the standard "source(s) before target"**.  This is mostly useful so you can have the target before the source when using something like `find ... -exec cp -t target/ {} +`, or so you can avoid using `-I {}` with `xargs` (which is much slower, it causes `xargs` to fork one command per arg, rather than fit as many as it can on each command line), e.g. `... | xargs -0r mv -t target/` instead of `... | xargs -0r -I {} mv {} target/`

Without an explicit override option as mentioned above, "target before source" is almost unheard of - so rare that you're fully entitled to think "Huh? WTF?" if you ever encounter it.

---

If you need to `scp` multiple files to multiple machines at once, do it in a for loop like this:

```
for h in host1 host2 host3... ; do
  scp file1 file2 file3... "user@$h:/path/"
done
```

Or use `pdcp` [from Parallel Distributed Shell](https://github.com/grondo/pdsh).  `pdsh` is packaged for most linux distributions.

e.g.

```
pdcp -w host1,host2,host3 file1 file2 file3 /path/to/target/
```

That's a very simple example, `pdsh` has a config file you can use to define hosts and groups of hosts with arbitrary group names (e.g. `all`, `webservers`, `dbservers`, `gpunodes`, or whatever).  You can then use them in `pdsh` or `pdcp` commands:

```
pdsh -g all 'uname -a ; uptime'
pdcp -g webservers index.html /var/www/
```

Unlike the `for` loop above, it doesn't run commands or copy the files sequentially, one host at a time.  It runs multiple commands in parallel, with reasonable limits based on the number of CPU cores your machine has.

Comment: And I can have multiple sources or multiple targets with scp?

Comment: multiple sources, yes.  multiple targets, no.   run `scp` multiple times with different targets (or use something like `pdcp` from `pdsh`) if you want that.

Comment: @robsch as cas suggested, you can have multiple sources, like `scp file1.sql file2.sh user@remote:~/upload`

Comment: btw, `pdsh` (parallel distributed shell) is packaged for most distros.  source is at https://github.com/grondo/pdsh.  home page used to be at llnl.gov (they developed it for use with HPC clusters, and it looks like the primary dev still works at LLNL) but the pdsh home page URL now just redirects to some usage info for their clusters.

Answer (score 2):

With the `scp` command, you can specify the **source** (the file or directory to be copied) and the **target** (the location in which to copy the file or directory).
The syntax for `scp` is:

If you are on the computer from which you want to send file to a remote computer:

```
scp /file/to/send username@remote:/where/to/put
```

Here the `remote` can be a FQDN or an IP address.

On the other hand if you are on the computer wanting to receive file from a remote computer:

```
scp username@remote:/file/to/send /where/to/put
```

Comment: So it's `scp from to`?

Comment: @robsch yes, basic syntax says that merely. copy *from* /path *to* /path/

Answer (score 0):

You can infer it from the `...` part.

You can copy multiple source files, but only to a single target. The `...` means you can specify additional files at this position. Since the `...` is given directly after `file1`, this must be the source.

Example: `scp fileA fileB fileC` would copy `fileA` and `fileB` to `fileC`.